# How to set empty string in JComboBox even if data available?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a combo box. The values are populating in combo box from DB. But I want to display empty.

Only when I selecting, it should be displayed in the drop down.

Example:

```
Select Item:   
""
Book
Library
Notebook
Computer
```

Here Book, Library will come from database. But I need to display first time empty string. I have tried:

```
combo.setSelectedItem("");
```

But it's always displaying "Book" only.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
setSelectedIndex(-1)
```

That should do it.